# Super User notifications

Tags: support, notifications

I tried asking this in chat, but there has been no one in the room for hours.  I am in Western Australia, GMT+8.

**Is there a way to be notified by Superuser.com when someone replies to a comment, or comments on your answer**?

It is a pain to have manually check each question/answer page.

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at these questions over on Meta Stack Overflow:

> [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)
>
> [Now that we have a global inbox, do we still need the Top Bar notifications?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65809/now-that-we-have-a-global-inbox-do-we-still-need-the-top-bar-notifications)

---

From Stack Overflow Blog

[The New Global Inbox](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/new-global-inbox/)

> Well, I’m pleased to announce we’ve
>   added a new global inbox to every site
>   in our network. On the Stack Exchange
>   logo in the upper left hand corner,
>   the one you already know and love —
>   you may see a new, small red numeric
>   indicator light up:
>
> That small red number tells you how
>   many new replies you have across the
>   entire Stack Exchange network of
>   websites. And by replies, I mean:
>
> - New answers to your questions
> - New comments on your posts
> - @replies to you in comments
>
> Click the number to go directly to the
>   global inbox.
>
> At any given time, the inbox will
>   contain a list of the last 30 global
>   messages for your account, along with:
>
> - The site icon, so you know which site the message is from
> - The title of the question the message is associated with
> - A preview excerpt of the first few characters of the message
> - The relative age of the message (in a tooltip, so hover your mouse to see
>     it)

Comment: The fact that the envelope was blue never implied to me that I had a new message.  Just realised I had notifications delivered to me.  Thanks.

Comment: @Steve: The blue envelope only seems to be used for other updates these days.  Comment reply notification comes through on the StackExchange dropdown menu in the top-left corner of the website now.

Comment: @Sathya: thanks for the updates - saw them a while back, but didn't think to thank until now :P